# Combining Window Keybindings in Metacity?

Tags: gnome, metacity

I'm using Metacity and I tried combining 2 Window Keybindings
 to one shortcut, essentially what I did was trying to create a 
Keybinding Command (gconf.. /apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/) 
Wrote there move_to_side_w | maximize_vertically . 
Obviously that didn't work because its trying to run those commands 
and they are only valid as window_keybindings... 
Long Story short: 
how do I combine 2 window_keybindings into 1 command ? 
(I'm sure it is possible with the keybindings_commands...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I think you can get to such an end-result is to write a shell script that uses [`wmctrl`](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) to do those both, then assign a hotkey to that shell script (System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts->Add).

Comment: That worked perfectly, wrote a shell script and everything, just one thing: is there a way to auto-detect the screen size (so the width size that I would give would be exactly half of the full width) ?